# using if statement under using case

Tags: c#, if-statement, using-statement

this says need to return path but i cant reach if cases is there any way ? thanks

```
public IEnumerable<RequestCall> GetRequests(string erisim, string sube, string sicil)
{
    using (var redisclient = RedisManager.GetClient())
    {
        var redisUser = redisclient.As<RequestCall>();

        if (erisim == "A")
        {
            return redisUser.GetAll();// .Where(c=>c.Sube=="Y");
        }
        else if (erisim == "P")
        {
            return redisUser.GetAll().Where(c => c.Sube == sube);
        }
        else if (erisim == "C")
        {
            return redisUser.GetAll().Where(c => c.CagriAcan == sicil);
        }

    }
}
```

this says need to return path but i cant reach if cases is there any way ? thanks

Comment: add one more `else` block and `return` the defualt value

Comment: What if `erisim` isn't any of `A`, `P` or `C`? You're describing a function that's meant to return an `IEnumerable<RequestCall>` but don't tell the compiler what to do in this case.

Comment: its only char; example if erisim char == p return sube if erisim == c return sicil like

Comment: @user3790322 - that's not what the function signature says - you've defined it as `string` which means it *could* be `I am the very model of a modern major general` - there's nothing here to tell the compiler (or anyone else) that it's strictly limited to one of only 3 options.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You say "this says" - *what* says? I'd assume that you're getting a compilation error, but this isn't clear from your question. If you are getting a compilation error, can you include the *exact* text of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
if (erisim == "A")
{
    return redisUser.GetAll();// .Where(c=>c.Sube=="Y");
}
else if (erisim == "P")
{
    return redisUser.GetAll().Where(c => c.Sube == sube);
}
else if (erisim == "C")
{
    return redisUser.GetAll().Where(c => c.CagriAcan == sicil);
}
else
{
    return Enumerable.Empty<RequestCall>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sudhakar Tillapudi, absolutely right, you need to add deafult clause:

```
using (var redisclient = RedisManager.GetClient())
{
    var redisUser = redisclient.As<RequestCall>();

    if (erisim == "A")
    {
        return redisUser.GetAll();// .Where(c=>c.Sube=="Y");
    }
    else if (erisim == "P")
    {
        return redisUser.GetAll().Where(c => c.Sube == sube);
    }
    else if (erisim == "C")
    {
        return redisUser.GetAll().Where(c => c.CagriAcan == sicil);
    }
    else return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you aren't accounting for the scenario where `erisim` does not equal `A`, `B` or `C` therefore the compiler doesn't know what to return.

It's generally neater to have a single exit point in a function, so instead of having multiple `return` statements, have a single return *value* e.g.

```
var result = null;
if (erisim == "A") 
{
    result = ...;
} 
else if (erisim == "P") 
{
    result = ...;
} 
else if (erisim == "C") 
{
    result = ...;
}
return result;
```

This approach will force you to define *something* to return (even if none of the statements are true) so you should never get those types of compiler errors.

Comment: Um. The compiler error forces you to return something. You can't have a logical error and forget to return something. Unlike here where you can now have a logical error and forget to assign to `result` in one of your branches. Congratulations, you've transformed a potential compile time error into a potential runtime error.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever well first of all, as far as I am aware the compiler won't let you use an unassigned variable so your logical error comment is void (little programming pun for ya). And secondly, that's exactly what I was referring to, the compiler is going to force you to return something, this approach forces you to *think* about what to return if none of those statements pass. It's purely a style choice and I was simply offering a different angle.

Comment: you assigned it `null` at the top of your `if` stack. The OP was *already* receiving a compiler error.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yeah, purely an example. `null` might be an acceptable return value for that function (I have no idea what the function does so I can't elaborate on that). The point was demonstrating setting up a default value and overriding it but having a single exit point.

Comment: But my point is now that someone comes along and adds a new `if` block - they do a bit of work and forget to assign `result`. This will not be caught by the compiler. Compare that with the original code/accepted answer where, if I had done the same but forgotten to `return` I'd now be getting a compiler error that not all paths return a result.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ah ok, I see the point you are making. However, that's easily resolved by not setting the initial default value at the top which would throw "*use of unassigned*" error if `result` was *never* set. Like I said, it's a style choice, the chances of the developer forgetting to set `result` using an approach like this is pretty slim in my opinion. However, I do take your point.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify:

Not all code paths in your code are returning `IEnumerable<RequestCall>`. For example, what if I pass the parameter erisim the value "X". That won't pass the 1st, 2nd or 3rd `if` statements. Then, your method exits, without returning anything (which is giving you the error message).

param `erisim`:

> ```
>    -> "A" -> return something
>    -> "P" -> return something
>    -> "C" -> return something
>    -> Anything else -> (this part is missing!)
> ```

As others said, you need `else` to cover the remanining cases. Or just return `Enumerable.Empty<RequestCall>();` before the end of the method.

Also, as a word of advice, you could use `enums` instead of "magic" strings if possible, or at least constants.